# Start TorBrowser with "firefox.exe" instead with "Start Tor Browser.exe"

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows

I usually execute TBB from an usb key but sometimes, firefox does not start correctly.
I've try to start TBB directly with "firefox.exe" and seem to be all ok, but start TorBrowser with "firefox.exe" instead with "Start Tor Browser.exe", what consequence can it have?

I mean: what consequence can it have if I start TorBrowser Bundle directly with "firefox.exe" from Tor-directory instead of "Start Tor Browser.exe"?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I provided the wrong answer for your question. 
I first thought you are using Tor via your normal "firefox.exe" but you mean that you are starting "firefox.exe" from the Tor-directory `%TorBrowser/Browser/firefox.exe`.
So here is the (hopefully) right answer:

If you are starting `Start Tor Browser.exe` first and TorBrowser won't open instantly, first have a look in your Task Manager if `tor.exe` is running in your process list.
If it is running your TorBrowser should work just fine when starting it manually over `firefox.exe`.
Maybe you should have a look in the logs of Tor to see if it is running as it should before browsing the WWW with TorBrowser.

Comment: why (in the Tor-directory) opening  `tor.exe` doesn't do anything but opening `firefox.exe` does open Tor?

Answer (score 1):

With Tor Browser 4.0, the Windows "launcher" program has been eliminated.  The installer unzips the browser files and then creates a simple shortcut to firefox.exe.  So, if you use Tor Browser 4.0, starting firefox.exe directly should work fine.